# How do I make objects translucent but keep background images solid?

Tags: image, transparency

First of all, new to Blender (about 2 months now) so if this seems like a basic question, I apologize.  Here is my situation..

When modeling, I am using the Background Image for referencing front, back, and sides.  I am able to set the opacity/transparency of the images and model with the objects, but I am trying to do the reverse.

I am trying to figure how to set the opacity of all the objects in my viewport to be translucent, while leaving the Background Images with full solid opacity.  This way, I can easily see my drawing even through my objects.

When I do the translucent images, the lines begin to get hard for me to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

In Blender 2.8 and on, there is an option to enable translucency in a scene, called *X-Ray*. It can be found in the shading options in the viewport.

[image]

Once that is enabled, everything in the scene goes translucent. Images may also go translucent depending on how you imported them. If you import your reference by going <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, >*Image >Reference* they will stay fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn on x ray mode by
[image]

if you have pie menus addon installed, you can also choose `toggle x ray` after pressing <kbd>z</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use a PNG file with a transparent background to start with, this can be done in most photo editing software's like Photoshop or the free GIMP program.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site. I think the user wants to *avoid* having the background images transparent.